# Windows.Data.Json keep original order

Tags: c#, json, windows, uwp

Im trying to use the `Windows.Data.Json` (moving away from JSON.NET) to parse JSON from a server but it seems to mix up the order of items when looping (foreach) through the keys.

Is there any way to maintain the original order?

For example:

JSON:

```
{

"name1": "example",

"name2": "example",

"name3": "example",

"name4": "example"

}
```

When i do a string print out of the JsonObject it appears to be in the correct order but when i loop through them they get output in a different order.

For example:

```
foreach(string name in parsedJson.Keys)
{
}
```

Which outputs in this order

> "name3", "name2", "name1", "name4"

Answer (score 1):

> When i do a string print out of the JsonObject it appears to be in the correct order but when i loop through them they get output in a different order.

I made a demo and reproduced your problem. After researching, I found `JsonObject.Keys` is using [IDictionary.Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.collections.idictionary.keys(v=vs.105).aspx), which doesn't guarantee the order.If you want to loop through the JObject in correct order I suggest you using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

You can loop through the JSON Object using following codes:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
String jsonStr = "{\"name1\": \"example\",\"name2\": \"example2\",\"name3\": \"example3\",\"name4\": \"example4\"}";
JObject obj=JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties())
{
    string key = prop.Name;
    var value = prop.Value.ToString();
}
```